# Мастер по чему-то или мастер чего-то?

Tags: грамматика

Чем отличаются значения словосочетаний: `мастер ключей` или `мастер по ключам`? В каких случаях правильно писать `мастер чего-то`, а в каких – `мастер по чему-то`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово ["Мастер"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) может иметь различные значения. В частности,

> "мастер" = "квалифицированный рабочий"
>   "мастер" = "человек, достигший высокого искусства в своем деле"

Сочетание "*мастер по ...*" однозначно указывает на первое и исключает второе. Соответственно "мастер по ключам" - это работник. А "мастер ключей" - это, вероятнее всего, ошибочный перевод (aka "надмозг") английского выражения "*master key*" (специально сделанный ключ, которым можно открыть любую дверь в доме).

Comment: "мастер ключей" может еще быть должностью/титулом, что-то вроде ключника, но почетнее. На английском это было бы наверное "Key Master", или "Master of Keys".

Comment: @Alissa Разве что в каком-нибудь фэнтези. Исторически был только ключник / ключница (housekeeper).

Comment: Или в придуманной организации. И это если говорить именно о ключах. Мне кажется, что в реальности существуют должности с аналогичным названием. Хотя я могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 2):

(В качестве дополнения)

Типичные примеры использования выражения "**мастер чего-то**". Чаще всего так говорят о литераторах и людях искусства, выделяющихся каким-либо аспектом своего творчества:

**мастер слова** - тот, кто особенно красиво и умело излагает свои мысли средствами литературного языка (писатель, поэт, рассказчик, литературный переводчик, существенно реже - журналист); не всегда великого писателя называют мастером слова в этом аспекте;

**мастер короткого рассказа** (или иного конретного жанра) - о литераторе

**мастер пейзажа** (натюрморта или иного жанра живописи, скульптуры) - о художнике

**мастер дальнего паса** - напр. о футболисте

**мастер мистификации(-ий)** - об особенностях поведения, направленных на массовое введение людей в заблуждение по поводу чего-то - в любой области, не обязательно творческой (это может быть как личность вроде Гудини, Копперфильда, так и просто известный мошенник)

**Мастер перевоплощения** - об актёре

Comment: Заслуживает упоминания ещё устойчивое выражение «мастер своего дела».